# Cargar página completa y luego ejecutar video

Tags: nodejs

lo que necesito es que cuando cargue toda la página se reproduzca el video, tengo este código así, me aparece primero el cuadro de section y después el video, necesito que me salgan los dos al tiempo, gracias.

```js
<body>
    <video src="./img/tweet3.mp4" autoplay ></video>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
    
        <div class="tweets">
                    <font face="Arial"></font>
                    <script>
                        
                    function actualizar(){location.reload(true);}
                        var datos = <%- data %>;
                        setInterval("actualizar()",15000);
                        
                        
                           datos.forEach(function(tweet) {
                               
                                console.log(tweet['text']);
                                
                                document.write('<section> <font face="Arial"  style="color:white"> '+tweet['text']+'</font> </section>'); 
                           
                                
                            });
                            
                            
                    </script> 
                  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con la funcion **window.load**:
que espera a que todo el documento carge!

```js
function load(){
 let video = document.getElementById("video");
 video.innerHTML='<video width="400" controls autoplay><source src="https://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" type="video/ogg"></video>';

}
window.onload = load;
```

```html
<div id="video"></div>
```

**referencia:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload